# How can I select new created rows without old, unupdated row?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database that I'm searching through that is sometimes updated by another person. The way it is updated is terrible, but I can't change it. What happens is the updated numbers contain a "-1" or "-2". For example,

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

Whenever one ID is updated, a new row is created like so:

```
ID
1
1-1
2
3
4
```

In this case, 1 was updated. Both 1 and 1-1 show up in the table. If it's updated again, it looks like this:

```
ID
1
1-1
1-2
2
3
4
```

It makes me furious but I can't do anything about it. I would like to select the rows in a query such that I get

```
ID
1-2
2
3
4
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your IDs are strings since you can use `-` in them. You can create a saved query with your entire table and two additional columns:

```
OriginalID: IIf(InStr([ID],'-')=0,[ID],CInt(Left([ID],InStr([ID],'-')-1)))
```

and

```
Version: IIf(InStr([ID],'-')=0,0,CInt(Right([ID],Len([ID])-InStr([ID],'-'))))
```

This converts the number after the dash to an actual number (and zero for the original version).

Then use

```
SELECT [OriginalID] & IIF(Max([Version])=0,'','-' & Max([Version])) AS MaxID
FROM [MySavedQuery]
GROUP BY [OriginalID]
```

I have not had a chance to test this so there may be a parenthesis missing here or there or you may have to add a +1 or -1 to some lengths, but it should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

First, split off the part of the ID without the dash, and set it to 0 if there is no dash:

```
SELECT ID, 
    CLng(IIF(ID Like "*-*", Right(ID, Len(ID) - InStr(1, ID, "-")), 0)) As LastPartID,
    CLng(IIF(ID LIKE "*-*", Left(ID, InStr(1, ID, "-") - 1), ID)) As FirstPartID
From MyTable
```

If you save this as a separate query, the next query is simple:

```
SELECT FirstPartID & IIF(Max(LastPartID) = 0, "", "-" & Max(LastPartID))
FROM MyQuery
GROUP By FirstPartID
```